# PowerShell hash table and output to text files

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have written a script with the help of @Ansgar. Below is the code for the script. The script checks for Ping, RDP, Remote Registry and WMI checks for a remote computer. The server names are entered in a text file servernames.txt Once the script is exeecuted, the servers that are UP are recorded in a text file named Online.txt and the servers which are DOWN are recorded in Offline.txt The format for recording is below:

ONLINE.TXT

```
<servername>

PING             :    SUCCESS
RDP              :    SUCCESS
Remote Registry  :    SUCCESS
WMI              :    SUCCESS
```

OFFLINE.TXT

```
<servername>

PING             :    SUCCESS
RDP              :    FAIL
Remote Registry  :    SUCCESS
WMI              :    SUCCESS
```

This is the script that I have till now:

```
#Text file to pick the server names. Path is hard coded to c:\temp\serverlist.txt
$servers = Get-Content "C:\temp\serverlist.txt"

ForEach ($server in $servers)
{

   Write-Host `n
   Write-Host $server
   Write-Host `n

   #PING
   $ping = Test-Connection -ComputerName $server -Quiet -Count 1

   #RDP
   $rdp  = Test-NetConnection -ComputerName $server -CommonTCPPort RDP -InformationLevel Quiet

   #REMOTE REGISTRY
   $regkey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey   ([Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive]::LocalMachine,$server)
   $ref = $regkey.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall")

   #WMI
   $wmi  = Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * from Win32_PingStatus where Address = '$server'"

   $state_noun = @{
      $true  = 'SUCCESS'
      $false = 'FAIL'
   }

   $state_verb = @{
      $true  = 'SUCCEEDED'
      $false = 'FAILED'
   }

   $result = @"
      PING             :    $($state_noun[$ping])
      RDP              :    $($state_noun[$rdp])
      Remote Registry  :    $($state_noun[[bool]$ref])
      WMI              :    $($state_noun[[bool]$wmi])

"@ 
}
```

How can I output the servers and their results to the text files (online.txt and offline.txt)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use `>` or `Out-File`

Comment: @Raf I can get the Out-File to work but how can I redirect FAIL status server to Offline.txt and SUCCESS status server to Online.txt? I am new to the hashtable concepts.

Comment: I just tried this logic and it doesnt write the results to the files:    If($result -contains 'FAIL')
    { 
        $result | Out-File c:\temp\offline.txt
    }
    elseif($result -contains 'SUCCESS')
    {
        $result | Out-File c:\temp\online.txt
    }

Comment: The -contains operator is not the same as string.Contains().  The -contains operator is used to know if a collection has a certain element (ie, @(1,2,3) -contains 3).  Try $result.Contains( 'FAIL' ) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`-and`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) to calculate the overall result of your 4 checks:

```
$ping -and $rdp -and [bool]$ref -and [bool]$wmi
```

The `-and` operator returns true only if both operands are true, so the above statement only becomes true when all 4 checks succeeded.

Write to one or the other output file depending on the outcome of the boolean operation:

```
if ($ping -and $rdp -and [bool]$ref -and [bool]$wmi) {
  $result | Out-File 'C:\path\to\online.txt' -Append
} else {
  $result | Out-File 'C:\path\to\offline.txt' -Append
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use the -Contains operator as previously suggested and just do something like:

```
If(@($state_noun[$ping],$state_noun[$rdp],$state_noun[[bool]$ref],$state_noun[[bool]$wmi]) -contains "FAIL"){
    $result | Out-File 'C:\path\to\online.txt' -Append
}else{
    $result | Out-File 'C:\path\to\offline.txt' -Append
}
```

Though I would personally use Ansgar Wiechers's solution. I just posted this as a proof of concept (I think that's the right term).